# TrimEnd not erase last spaces

Tags: c#, string, trim

I want to copy selected rows from my data grid view to clipboard
And it's work perfect, just one thing: I not success to remove last 3 spaces from the string.
(I also try: `clipboard.Remove(clipboard.Length - 3)` and `clipboard.Trim()`, but both not working too)

My function:

```
private void menuCopyClipboard_wholeRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region calculate spaces
    int[] spaces = new int[8]; // I have 8 columns in the data grid view
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        spaces[i] = 0;


    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in datagridview1.SelectedRows)
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in datagridview1.Columns)
        {
            int cellLength = datagridview1.Rows[dgvr.Index].Cells[dgvc.Index].FormattedValue.ToString().Length;
            if (spaces[dgvc.Index] < cellLength)
               spaces[dgvc.Index] = cellLength;
        }
    #endregion

    string clipboard = "";
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in datagridview1.SelectedRows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in datagridview1.Columns)
                clipboard += String.Format("{0, -" + spaces[dgvc.Index] + "}   ", // 3 spaces between columns
                                           datagridview1.Rows[dgvr.Index].Cells[dgvc.Index].FormattedValue.ToString());

        if (dgvr.Index != 0 && datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count > 1) clipboard += "\n"; // to not add enter after last line nor copy one line
    }

    clipboard.TrimEnd(); // <-- doens't erase spaces
    Clipboard.SetText(clipboard);
}
```

The problem: The spaces not erased, as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

(The question: what wrong? why the spaces are not erased?)

Comment: `clipboard = clipboard.Trim();`

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I try this. it's not work

Comment: but you add "\n" at the end of the string. See in the debugger which is the value of clipboard before the Trim().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Strings are immutable.**

That beeing said, a string manipulating method like TrimEnd() will always return a new string.

So doing this:

```
clipboard = clipboard.Trim();
```

will just fix your problem.

If you also need to remove the `\n` you can use this:

```
char[] trimChars = new char[]{' ','\n'};
clipboard = clipboard.TrimEnd(trimChars);
```

Comment: thank you, the seconds solution work: `char[] trimChars = new char[] { ' ', '\n' };` but I not understand why, I not insert new line after the last line... (last index in the loop is zero...)

Answer (score 1):

TrimEnd() removes all trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object, and returns the resultant string, so you should receive the converted string.

```
char[] charsToTrim = {' '};
clipboard = clipboard.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
if (dgvr.Index != 0 && datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count > 1) clipboard += "\n"; // to not add enter after last line nor copy one line
```

You're adding a "\n" at the ending of the string, that's prevent the Trim to work try trimming before adding the "\n".

```
if (dgvr.Index != 0 && datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count > 1) clipboard = clipboard.Trim() + "\n"; // to not add enter after last line nor copy one line
else clipboard = clipboard.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
clipboard.Trim();
```

Instead of :

```
clipboard.TrimEnd();
```

Comment: This would just result in the same. Just see my answer.